Rebbe Maharash studying Nigleh during night
Is it correct to say, as I once heard, that the Rebbe Maharash would learn Oral Torah the entire night while standing? I don't how to understand this statement, because of two conflicting facts, neither of which speaks of learning Oral Torah at this hour. First, the Rebbe RaShaB wrote in his Kuntres Etz haChaim that one should specifically only learn Chassidus before Shacharit. Second, it also says in Shulchan Aruch haRav that one should study Oral Law at this time.

Welcome to MI Yodeya! This site is different from other sites. Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Are you looking for a source? What is your question?

I would have to see the specific source, but I assume the Rashab was referring to the morning hours, not the entire night preceding shacharis.

See Chap. 25 of Kuntres Etz haChaim.Those who rise early in the morning should study Chassidus for the entire time before prayer, nothing aside from Chassidus. For there's enough time during the day to study Nigleh. Those who rise early and study Chassidus may compensate for this time by reducing their study of Chassidus at night (provided this will fit the measure of time mentioned above). But they must also study some Chassidus at night, for it is necessary to study Chassidus at night."
